# Count specific characters in a cell - Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to count all special characters (!%_*?+-,) in a cell.

For example:

[image]

With this formula `=LEN(D2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2;"!";""))` i can only count one character, but i need to count multiple characters in single cell...is there a way how to tweak this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you considered `Regex`? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) for a great starting point...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using formulas only, not VBA, this is possible with the following two approaches:

Consider the text in `A1`:

First approach:

Multiple nested `SUBSTITUTE`:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),"-",""),"+",""),"?",""),"*",""),"_",""),"%",""),"!",""))
```

Second approach:

Using `SUMPRDUKT` for getting the `MID` function in array context to get each single charachter of the string in `A1` compared with each single special character:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MID(A1,ROW($1:$1000),1)={"!","%","_","*","?","+","-",","}))
```

Comment: like the sumproduct option with the static array list

Comment: Good non-VBA solution. See [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_special_characters) for permissible special characters (not sure if OP only wants to count characters he specifies...)

Comment: Hi @AxelRichter, did you test your second formula? It's not working for me. I'd suggest `=SUMPRODUCT({1}*NOT(ISNA(MATCH(MID(A1,ROW($1:$1000),1),{"!","%","_","*","?","+","-",","},0))))`.

Comment: @Ulli Schmid: Yes, I have tested it and it works. With German Excel it is: `=SUMMENPRODUKT(--(TEIL(A6;ZEILE($1:$1000);1)={"!"."%"."_"."*"."?"."+"."-".","}))`. Note, the array literal must be a row vector.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. Thanks ;). {"!"\"%"\"_"\"*"\"?"\"+"\"-"\","} worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a simple array formula:

```
=SUM(LEN(A2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,Special_Characters,"")))
```

`Special_Characters` is a range listing all your special characters.  You could manually enter them as an array constant if you prefer:

```
=SUM(LEN(A2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,{"%";"_";"*";"?";"+";"-";",";"!"},"")))
```

but the named range seems simpler.

---

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces **`{...}`** around the formula.

[image]

If you prefer a VBA solution, I would suggest the code below.  You will need to modify `.Pattern` to include any other characters you do NOT want to count.  In the code below, any character that is not an upper or lower case letter, or a digit, will be counted as a special character.

```
Option Explicit
Function SpecialChars(S As String) As Long
    Dim RE As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9]"
    SpecialChars = Len(S) - Len(.Replace(S, ""))
End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple version I created:

```
Function CountSpecialCharacters(rng As Range) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp, matches As MatchCollection

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" '~~~> this counts any character not a to z or a number
    End With

    Set matches = regEx.Execute(rng)

    CountSpecialCharacters = matches.Count
End Function
```

Two points:

1. In the VBA editor you need to set `References > Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5`
2. You call the function on your spreadsheet e.g. `=CountSpecialCharacters(A2)`

Answer (score 0):

=8*LEN(D2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2;"!";""))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2;"%";""))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2;"_";""))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2;"*";"")) -LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2;"?";""))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2;"+";""))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2;"-";""))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(D2;",";""))